# Crashlytics says that upload of log is complete, yet nothing is in the dashboard

Tags: android

`05-15 13:50:53.442 28150-28193/app I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: <ID>`

Yet my Dashboard says that there are 0 issues, 0 non-fatals and 0 users.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. The most likely cause of not seeing a crash on Android is that the app hasn't been fully activated. Do you see the specific package name on your Fabric dashboard?

Comment: Thanks for answer @mike-bonnel. Yes, I have seen the specific package name on Fabric dashboard. Futhermore, the "Releases" page used to show that I have "66.7% crash-free users" and "3 crashes" (app crashes on specific android versions, testing phase); but there was notihng in "Crashlytics" tab, e.g. it still said that I'm "100% crash-free". However, the issue has fixed itself: after about 1.5 hours the crash reports have shown.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks Mikhail. There are two things I can think of - 1) our servers had a temporarily delay in processing the crashes or 2) even with the upload complete, something happened where the crash didn't make it over, but our SDK thought it had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure, that you have Crashlytics SDK as the last line of dependencies block in your app's build.gradle.

```
dependencies {

    ...

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: How this should help?